# merging assembly and C in mplab

Tags: c, assembly, mplab

I want use a procedure written in assembly for PIC in my c code in MPLABX. is there a way I can do this. I have searched over the internet but can't find anything helpful on this.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using a 16-bit PIC, see **8.3 MIXING ASSEMBLY LANGUAGE AND C VARIABLES AND FUNCTIONS** in [MPLAB® C30 User’s Guide](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/devicedoc/c30_users_guide_51284f.pdf).

> **EXAMPLE 8-2: CALLING AN ASSEMBLY FUNCTION IN C**
>
> ```
>    /*
>     ** file: call1.c
>     */
>     extern int asmFunction(int, int);
>     int x;
>     void main(void)
>     {
>         x = asmFunction(0x100, 0x200);
>     }
> ```
>
> The assembly-language function sums its two parameters and returns the result.
>
> ```
>     ;
>     ; file: call2.s
>     ;
>       .global _asmFunction
>     _asmFunction:
>       add w0,w1,w0
>       return
>      .end
> ```
>
> Parameter passing in C is detailed in **Section 4.12.2 “Return Value”**. In the preceding 
>   example, the two integer arguments are passed in the W0 and W1 registers. The 
>   integer return result is transferred via register W0. More complicated parameter lists 
>   may require different registers and care should be taken in the hand-written assembly 
>   to follow the guidelines.